# Java.lang.classnotfoundexception - HelloWorld.class

Tags: java, class, compilation, classnotfoundexception

Can't seem to get my head around what is causing this error. I have set the CLASSPATH in Environment Variables to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin`.

I can compile the code into a `.class` file using `javac HelloWorld.java`. However when trying to run the `.class` file using `java HelloWorld`, I am getting the below error:

I am running the code from `C:\Java` which is the directory of both my `.java` and `.class` file.

```
 c:\Java>java HelloWorld
 Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

CODE:

```
public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the class file located in the folder where you try to run it from (c:\Java)?

Comment: Set your classpath where is your .class file is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLASSPATH environment variable is not supposed to point the location of your java installation (you don't really need any environment variable to point at that. A few outdated tools MIGHT need you to set JAVA_HOME, but not to the 'bin' dir but to its parent).

It is supposed to point to the location(s) of your class files.

If your `HelloWorld.class` file has no package declaration and is located at `C:\java\HelloWorld.class`, then `C:\java` needs to be your classpath.

You can use CLASSPATH for this, but... don't. You can have multiple projects on a machine so the notion of 'one machine, one classpath' is silly. Use command line params:

java -cp c:\java HelloWorld

Comment: Thanks for this, I was getting confused with the PATH and CLASSPATH variables, going to use parameters as advised, thanks

Answer (score 2):

if your classpath,

```
CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin
```

Your class loader will look .class files from there,

include your current directory into your CLASSPATH, where as in your case your .class files are at `C:\Java`, so the `java` could not find your .class file, try this one

```
CLASSPATH=C:\Java
```

`CLASSPATH` variable is where `java` looks for `.class` and `jar` file paths

[PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: do we need the JDK path in there?

Comment: no we don't, i thought may he needs it.

Comment: well, no `.class` (or `.jar`) there anyway.,..

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought I had read somewhere the class path needs to be set to the JDK directory so it knows how to launch "javac" etc

Comment: ok, path and classpath are different.